# Managing session attributes to access in all web application

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, web-applications, jsf-2

Well, I have some session attributes that must be acessible to all application (DAO, Business Object, Beans and others).

I can't create a class with static attribute because static attributes are shared to different sessions.

I.E: User login in application and i need save the hour of login, i need store this value in a session attribute because in some point of my application like BO (Business Object) i will need know when user log in application.

I can't acess HttpRequest in some places of my application, i need some another solution.

Comment: Your question reads like there is a more fundamental design issue with the application. The business objects are supposed to be providing the service to other components in the application, not the other way round. The business objects should be in-place as at the points where the necessary information is being provided, so components can just call the business method, on-demand (as against just stashing some info somewhere and then having the biz objects pulling data). All, told, you can try with an `@ApplicationScoped` bean that has a map of the data you're interested in

Comment: I upped @kolossus but he want's session scoped not @/ApplicationScoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write a POJO that contains all of the "request scoped" attributes that you need, such as the "hour of login";
2. Write a [javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html):

   ```
   public PojoFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

       private static final ThreadLocal<Pojo> POJO = new ThreadLocal<Pojo>();

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
            try {
                Pojo pojo = createPojoFrom(request);
                POJO.set(pojo);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } finally {
                POJO.remove();
            }
       }

       public static currentPojo() {
           return POJO.get();
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Call PojoFilter.currentPojo() where ever you need these values.

Clearly this can be designed a lot better so that the filter doesn't leak into the rest of the code but this should give you the idea.

Comment: So, I imagine that i can create a Map of ThreadLocal where i can return a ThreadLocal with a specific name and a specific value. Each session will be a different value to this MAP, is it correct ?

Comment: I don't think so. The neat thing about ThreadLocal is that each thread of control gets a separate instance of the Pojo that you create. So if your application is handling N requests on N threads, then there will be N different Pojos in existence for the duration of each request. Your Pojo could be a Map<K, V> if you wanted, but that's a very loose abstraction

Comment: I can't understand your ideia, can you give me more details ?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this in JSF so I'm going to give you a jsf response and/or generic.

a) create a `@SessionScoped` - ManagedBean and apply your values to it and then `@ManagedProperty` inject it into your requires locations you want to access it (create a facade if you want).

b) just create a 'data model' object store your info in it and set it into the session. E.g

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userContext", context);
```

Comment: The second solution is very good and elegant but the problem is that when i try access the FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() this return NULL.

Comment: Then are you sure you're actually using JSF?

Answer (score 0):

```
Since user id is unique, we can utilize this fact to implement your problem in simpler way as follows(My solution consider that all incoming request goes through common servlet/filter, I am using filter here):

a) Create a utility class as:

public class AppUtlity {
    private static Map<String, Date> userLoginTimeStampMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();

    public static void addLoginTimeStamp(String userId) {
        synchronized(AppUtlity.class) {
            Date date = new Date();
            userLoginTimeStampMap.put(userId, date);
        }
    }

    public static Date getUserLoginTimeStamp(String userId) {
        synchronized(AppUtlity.class) {
            return userLoginTimeStampMap.get(userId);
        }
    }
}

b) In doFilter method of your filter write code as below:
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
         try {
             String userId = user.getUserId();
             AppUtlity.addLoginTimeStamp(userId);
         } finally {
             // do whatever u want to do
         }
    }

c) Now in any class like service or dao, you can easily get user login timestamp as below:

Date date = AppUtlity.getUserLoginTimeStamp(userId);

I hope this solution is feasible.
```